# Was Shmi Skywalker Force Sensitive?

Tags: star-wars

Is there anything to show if [Shmi Skywalker](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shmi_Skywalker) (Anakin's Mother) was Force-sensitive?

And, along that line, is there anything to indicate that the whole "*virgin birth through midi-chlorian fiat*" or the "*virgin birth via Plagueis playing with the Force*" would not be possible unless she were Force-sensitive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is probably safe to say that she wasn't Force-sensitive, mainly because it further adds to the legend of Anakin, but I don't think it is ever truly established.

As far as your second question pertaining to the possibility of a non-Force-sensitive producing a messianic Force birth, The [Darth Plagueis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Darth_Plagueis) novel makes two things clear relating to midi-chlorians:

> Midi-chlorians exist in all lifeforms, this is shown when Plagueis manipulates King Veruna's midi-chlorians (who did not possess enough of them to be considered to be Force-sensitive), which in turn slowly killed him. The other item that the novel establishes, is that Anakin was born as a direct result of midi-chlorians thwarting Plagueis' attempt at tipping the balance of the force towards the dark side.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Star Wars Episode I: Visual Dictionary](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_I_The_Visual_Dictionary)

> *Shmi can always sense when Anakin is nearby, even when she cannot see or hear him*

I think Shmi Skywalker is Force sensitive, just like Chirrut Îmwe

Comment: Or could it be that she only has the normal number of midi-chlorians but that Anakin is such a powerful presence in the Force that she can feel him anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Per the Legends<sup>*</sup> factbook [*Star Wars: Graphics*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Graphics), Shmi is not a 'Force *Sensitive*' (e.g. someone who can actively sense the Force) as she possesses a midi-chlorian count of just 3,300, less than half that needed to be classed as such. That being said, her slightly elevated numbers do suggest that she has a more *general sensitivity* to the Force.

> [image]

<sup>*</sup>Astoundingly, these figures seem to have been taken from the [**fake** midi-chlorian numbers](https://web.archive.org/web/20050204223101/http://www.supershadow.com/starwars/midi.html) invented by [noted Star Wars fabulist SuperShadow](https://web.archive.org/web/20200308021521/https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/SuperShadow) and should be treated with great caution.

Comment: “Supershadow is canon.”

Comment: @SillybutTrue - Well, published, at least.

Answer (score -2):

I think she is. When Anakin proposes he race for Qui Gon she says that Anakin is meant to help Qui Gon. I just can't think of any reason George Lucas used that wording given we know he changed McGregor's dialogue.

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if you could find a quote from George backing it up.